# Footer/Header in a ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I am not able to get a header/footer working with the listView. I have tried lot of approaches but I don't know where I am going wrong. Please find the basic code here.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip">

<Button android:id="@+id/previous"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String[] lakes = {
            "Superior",
            "Victoria",
            "Huron",
            "Michigan",
            "Tanganyika",
            "Baikal",
            "Great Bear Lake",
            "Great Slave Lake",
            "Erie",
            "Winnipeg",
            "Ontario",
            "Balkhash",
            "Ladoga",
            "Vostok",
            "Onega",
            "Titicaca",
            "Nicaragua",
            "Athabasca" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        RelativeLayout listFooterView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.addFooterView(listFooterView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lakes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

If I remove the listView.addFooterView(listFooterView); , the application works and the listView is displayed. However including this statement makes the application to crash. Kindly let me know the solution to this problem.

Regards
Anubhav

Comment: Post your logcat stacktrace section.

Comment: somehow I restarted the application and it started working. But if the list is long, the button (part of footer) comes at the end of the list after scrolling. What I want is the button to be fixed at the bottom of the screen through out and then the listView should scroll in the remaining space.

Comment: put your button android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"

Comment: The functionality you describe is how a footer will work (at the end of the list).  You will need to layout your footer, as a seperate component, and put it in your activity below your listview.  In other words, you wouldn't use the listview.footer function.